# Как настроить развертывание JavaFX приложения, чтобы запаковать разные источники .sh и .jars и бинарные Линукс файлы?

Tags: javafx

Как настроить развертывание JavaFX приложения, чтобы запаковать разные источники .sh и .jars и бинараные Линукс файлы?

```
              <fx:application name="${application.title}" 
                              mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
              <fx:resources>
                  <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}"
                              includes="*.jar, .*.sh"/>
              </fx:resources>
              <fx:info title="${application.title}" 
                       vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
            </fx:deploy>          
         </target>
        <!--
```

Comment: приведенный фрагмент - это что?

Comment: это из build.xml Нетбинса, если и Вы это не узнали, Вы точно не можете мне помочь и ответить на вопрос

Comment: я разрабатывал NB. Мой вопрос про то, зачем этот фрагмент в вопросе?